# A charged particle in a mass spectrometer travels approximately the speed of sound. Do charged particles share similar properties with sound waves?

Tags: acoustics, mass-spectrometry

I've calculated the speed of a charged particle in a mass spectrometer through the Bernoulli equation to be around the speed of sound.  I've also seen marketing videos from mass spectrometer vendors saying the charged particles travel at sonic or super sonic speeds.  What is the similarity between sounds waves and charged particles in a mass spectrometer?  Or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Don't they have a high vacuum in the mass spectrometer chamber? Where do you apply Bernoulli equation? And the speed of sound in what? In air?

Comment: Hi nasu, yes all mass spectrometer are held under vacuum.  The first chamber in the mass spectrometer is at a pressure of 8-12 Torr.  And the subsequent chamber gets down to 1-3 Torr.  As for the Bernoulli equation, the charged particles are first introduced at 1 atm at a relatively low speed (~0 m/s).  When they enter the first vacuum region, the charged particles have accelerated to a speed nearly identical to the speed of sound in air.  So my question is if this speed is coincidental to the speed of sound in air or if the charged particles exhibit some similar property to sound waves.

Comment: Do you have a reference showing that the particles are accelerated in air at atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Here is one source: https://scs.illinois.edu/resources/cores-scs-service-facilities/mass-spectrometry-lab/services/electrospray-ionization
"The ESI source operates at atmospheric pressure."
This is for a mass spectrometer that is equipped with Electrospray Ionization (ESI).  This is the first chamber of a mass spectrometer where the in-solution ions are converted to gas-phase ions.  The ions then transfer to the chambers held under vacuum